# How to query CRM 2011 system from website

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am working on a project that requires me to get data out of a CRM system. I have been doing a lot of research and I'm thinking about using XrmServiceToolkit to execute fetchxml queries. The CRM system is run by an external company and I will be having a meeting with them soon, now I was wondering what do have to ask them to do for me to be able to query with the XrmServiceToolkit?

Comment: I need to know more about your situation. Mostly why and for what purpose? - If you are looking to run reports then Advanced Find or the SSRS Reporting within CRM is the way to go. - If you are looking to replicate the data into another database, then you can look at either the SDK, SSIS, or something like Cozy Roc or Scribe. - Lastly, if you are looking to create an instant web service to be consumed in another application, then the SDK is the approach you want to take.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to confirm that you have a service user set up using whose credentials you can query the data. You will just need to specify the entities you need to get data for and the CRM admin will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to access CRM data externally correct?

If so you're going to run into Cross-Site Scripting issues using JavaScript to access CRM, *unless* you have the same website setup underneath the CRM web site. This is I believe technically unsupported.

If you need to access CRM data from an external site, you're going to need to make the calls from managed code. Whether this is a proxy service that you can call into from your external site, or a full-fledged ASP.NET website you build from the ground up, you'll need to do that in order to avoid Cross-Site Scripting issues.

The managed code will have to handle authentication as well. You have two options here:

- You can pass through windows/network credentials if desired, but you'll need to make sure each user accessing the system is a user in CRM with the correct privileges.
- You can set the proxy/service/custom website up to use a specific user in CRM, but you'll need to note that whatever that user can see in CRM, the users that hit the custom proxy/service/site will be able to see (in theory).

Answer (score -1):

The XrmServiceToolkit is just a collection of javascript helper functions and wrappers.  I'm not sure exactly what actions have to be performed to give you access, but I can tell you, as long as your user has rights to the entities you're querying and you can hit the developer resources under Settings --> Customizations, you should be good [image: Developer Resources].